# Primefaces SelectOneMenu's ajax event inside outputPanel with rendered, is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've this code:

```
<p:outputPanel styleClass="ep-form-field-wrapper-s" rendered="#{monthlyProcessesReportsViewBean.showReports}">
                <p:outputLabel for="columnsConfig" value="#{i18n['monthly-processes-reports-columns-configuration']}" styleClass="ep-data-edit-field"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="columnsConfig" value="#{monthlyProcessesReportsModelBean.report}" effect="none" converter="#{genericUniqueEntityConverter}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{i18n['monthly-processes-reports-as-payslip']}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{monthlyProcessesReportsModelBean.reports}" var="report" itemValue="#{report}"
                                   itemLabel="#{report.description}"/>
                    <p:ajax listener="#{monthlyProcessesReportsBackingBean.handleReportTypeSelected(report)}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>

</p:outputPanel>
```

The ajax event is not working, but if I remove the rendered attribute from the outputPanel it works correctly. 
What is wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the link.
These are the dangers of the copy&paste: my monthlyProcessesReportsViewBean, which is used to store the property that manages the rendered attibute, was RequestScoped instead of ViewScoped and I'd not been noticed...